# Android: Memory Analyzer eclipse plugin(1.1) doesn't launch automatically when pressing ddms "hprof dump"

Tags: android, memory, analyzer, hprof

The older version 1.0 used to work fine. However after updating to 1.1 it gives an option to save hprof file. How can I open that file in eclipse?

Eclipse version is Helios 3.6.2

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To let DDMS convert it on-the-fly, set in Preferences Android -> DDMS -> HPROF Action: Open in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

1. Converted the generated android hrof file to mat hprof file:

`hprof-conv.exe c:/android.hprof c:/mat.hprof`

1. copied the generated file in the bin directory of the project
2. Refresh the project. Double click mat.hprof to open